# Get group photo: ErrorAccessDenied

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I can get a valid authtoken and I can use this token to successfully call other endpoints like "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups" and get valid results, using the client_credential flow.  However, I am trying to get group photo, that is used for teams:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/photos
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-photos

Problem is I am getting "ErrorAccessDenied" as the result, ie:

```
 { "error": { "code": "ErrorAccessDenied", "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.", "innerError": { "request-id": "e1936ac7-84f6-4cc6-be9e-e7feb38b5198", "date": "2019-11-28T23:26:10" } } }
```

I believe I have all the needed permissions:

[image]

Does anyone know what the problem is?